# Expect fully qualified resource Id that start with '/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}'

Tags: azure, templates, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Unable to use variables or parameters in ARM template where subscription id is required.

> "subnetRef": "[concat('/subscriptions/',parameters('subscriptionid'),'/resourceGroups/',parameters('vnetrg'),'/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/',parameters('vnet'),'/subnets/',parameters('subnet'))]",

Result:

> \"LinkedInvalidPropertyId\",\r\n    \"message\": \"Property id '[variables('subnetRef')' at path 'properties.ipConfigurations[0].properties.subnet.id' is invalid. Expect fully qualified resource Id that start with '/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}' or '/providers/{resourceProviderNamespace}/'.\"\r\n  }\r\n}"

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of how I've set up the `subnetRef` resourceID path. Use the `resourceId(...)` function to build up the path, picking up the subscription ID part for you.

```
"vnetID": "[resourceId(variables('networkResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks',variables('virtualNetworkName'))]",
"subnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetID'),'/subnets/',variables('subnetNameBack00'))]",
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#resourceid